# Online storage for collected WP7 app data

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm developing a WP7 application that collects users data and stores it in a cloud somewhere. This data can later be accessed by the user elsewhere. 
Now, anybody who can recommend a good and efficient way of this data storage? 
I was thinking of storing this data in the user's skydrive from which he can later access it.

Any other suggestions please?

Comment: Well, what's wrong with Skydrive?

Comment: Nothing actually is wrong, I just needed a second opinion on the thought.

Comment: You're the only one who knows your exact needs. If you run into some specific Skydrive limitations, we might be able to suggest another service. Otherwise, on which basis could we tell that a service is more appropriate than another? As long as it works, go for it.

Comment: Why not also add support for other online storage players like dropbox so you can maximize your user base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/). A cloud storage that has many features and has a [.NET SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/) too.

Comment: I actually went this way. Thanks!

Comment: I feel happy to be of any help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) which may be interesting for you. You can post debug info via simple http post request (no user interaction required, easy integration). But there are limitations for free account: 10 private records, max 15 requests a day.